# Custom validation rules on user signup

Tags: modules

I'm trying to add some rules for users signing up. The first two (`fullName` and `email`) work fine. However, the password rules are triggered no matter what. Even if the passwords match and are over 8 characters, it still fails.

```
Event::on(User::class, Model::EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE, static function (Event $event) {
  // If a user is already logged in we are not on the public registration page
  if (Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity()) {
    return;
  }
  $user = $event->sender;

  // Do the custom validation
  if (!$user->fullName) {
    $user->addError('fullName', Craft::t('yii', 'Please enter your name.'));
    $event->isValid = false;
  }

  if (!$user->email) {
    $user->addError('email', Craft::t('yii', 'Please enter a valid email.'));
    $event->isValid = false;
  }

  if (mb_strlen($user->password) < 8) {
    $user->addError('password', Craft::t('yii', 'Password must be more than 8 characters.'));
    $event->isValid = false;
  }

  if ($user->password != $user-> confirmPassword) {
    $user->addError('confirmPassword', Craft::t('yii', 'Passwords do not match'));
    $event->isValid = false;
  }
});
```

```
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input id="password" name="password" type="password">
{{ user ? forms.errorsList(user.getErrors('password')) }}

<label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
<input id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" type="password">
    {{ user ? forms.errorsList(user.getErrors('confirmPassword')) }}
</div>
```

Can anyone spot what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting a password during front end registration using the core `users/save-user` action, [Craft actually sets the `newPassword` attribute on the user model](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/6d73ac2bcd9be609e79028852711ac7c13c62309/src/controllers/UsersController.php#L1313) under the hood, not the `password` attribute.

*This means that you need to test the length for the `newPassword` attribute, not the `password` attribute, i.e.:*

```php
if (mb_strlen($user->newPassword) < 8) {
    $user->addError('password', Craft::t('yii', 'Password must be more than 8 characters.'));
    $event->isValid = false;
  }
```

Another issue with your code is the `if ($user->password != $user->confirmPassword) {` conditional.

The user model doesn't actually have a `confirmPassword` attribute, so it's odd if you're not seeing an exception thrown here (are you using [`devMode`](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/what-dev-mode-does) during development?). But regardless, the code is not going to work as intended.

Note that you also can't do `$user->addError('confirmPassword', ...)` – again, since the user model doesn't actually have that attribute; the `addError()` method only works with actual attributes.

Assuming `confirmPassword` is the name for an input in your registration form, you'll need to change your code to something like this (personally I think an if/else statement makes sense here, since you can't set separate errors on the model for the password and the "confirm password"):

```php
if (mb_strlen($user->newPassword) < 8) {
    $user->addError('password', Craft::t('yii', 'Password must be more than 8 characters.'));
    $event->isValid = false;
  } else if ($user->newPassword !== Craft::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParam('confirmPassword')) {
    $user->addError('password', Craft::t('yii', 'Passwords do not match'));
}
```

Beyond this, while doing custom validation in an `EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE` event handler should work, the recommended way to do custom validation in Craft is to add Yii validation rules via the `Element::EVENT_DEFINE_RULES` event. [Check out this page in the official docs.](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/extending-system-components.html#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed answer! My code was kind of hacked together from some old questions on here - shows I still have so much to learn. Thank you.